Usage of どうなりたい in this sentence?

I'm a bit stumbled on this use of どうなりたい here. As I can gather from the context, the character is essentially "Just because I like them, It doesn't mean I wanted to be their boyfriend. Even being as friends would have been fine"
For context, the character just found out his crush has a boyfriend and he's left pondering. I can gather so どうなりたい  should be "I want to be their boyfriend/special one" but I'm curious about what's the deal with it?

Related or duplicate How should I interpret どうなりたっかたんだろう

Do you also have difficulty with こうなりたい, ああなりたい, etc?
